# Multiple form for one entry

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am looking to make multiple form for one entry. My idea is to ask for user one to fill the first form, except one field of a list. On submission notify user two of the new submission and ask him to fill the field. It would really simplify the life of everybody in my company but I don't know if it is feasable.

I am using SharePoint server 2013. Do you know how could I do this work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be:

- List A where user one creates a list element
- List A has a Workflow notifying user two on item creation using tasks
- user two completes tasks using the task form
- the task creates an item in list B with information from list A + task form

Note that you can chose to have only one list and hide the field on item creation. You can also chose not to use task forms and only user action with a workflow initiation form.

The important bricks are here:
- You can chose a field visibility in new/edit/display forms (using PowerShell for example)
- You can use Workflows to automate behaviors on events (item creation or modification)
- You can use tasks to ask a user to take action (with forms potentially)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try it. When you are creating list B entry from list A, do I need to ask the user wich row the user is referring to ?

Comment: If you created your workflow correctly, the task/the workflow has the context (it has been created by an event on item A) and you should be able to retrieve any information you want.

Comment: Ok, I don't really see what's a workflow is, I just googled it and it seems to require SharePoint designer, is it necessary ? If yes can I ask for my superior to give me sharepoint designer knowing that I use Sharepoint server 2013 ?

Comment: SharePoint Designer is required to make workflows, it is a free software that you can download on official Microsoft pages. You may want to try and read some literature about SharePoint, Workflows & Tasks before developing such a solution, a clear mind is always a more proficient one :)

Comment: Yes thank that's what I'll do. So Sharepoint designer doesn't require some kind of authorization to connect to any Sharepoint ? Additionnaly do you have some reccommandation on where I can learn workflows & tasks ? Thanks

Comment: I just connected to the sharepoint, and the access isn't allowed from designer. I am actually an adminstrator for Sharepoint pages.

Comment: The official documentation is always the best. [How to create a workflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo), [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/) are very good start points. Concerning authentication with designer, its default authentication is your Windows user. If your SharePoint uses another ADFS or another authentication method, you'll have to change its options or launch it with cmd line parameters. You should google that according to your authentication method.